# How to create a login form using emberJS?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js

I would like create a login form using emberjs views. Any idea which controls I can use for this.

Does emberJS supports form control and other UI controls like, grid, list etch. I know it is framework for development, however it supports few controls like 
textField
textArea
Check box.

That said, why it is not supporting other controls like panel.

Comment: Ember.JS does not have built-in UI components past basic things like checkbox and textfields, take a look at [FlameJS](https://github.com/flamejs/flame.js) which is a widget library built on top of Ember. There have also been projects integrating existing frameworks with Ember, check out [jQuery-UI-Ember](https://github.com/lukemelia/jquery-ui-ember) or [Ember-Bootstrap](https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap)

Comment: Please click Accept on my answer if it was useful ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Davis got it right, however there are a few improvements to be made to his code.

1. `Ember.Button` is deprecated. Instead, use a `button` tag.
2. In your view, define a `submit` event. It will get triggered when your form is submitted. No need to manually set an action on the button.
3. Your views shouldn't be doing any `$.ajax` stuff. Delegate that to the controller.

So, after refactoring, the code will look something like this:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.loginController = Ember.Object.create({
    login: function(username, password) {
      // $.ajax stuff goes here
    }
});

App.LoginFormView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'form',
    username: null,
    password: null,

    submit: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var username = this.get('username');
        var password = this.get('password');

        this.get('controller').login(username, password)
    },
});
```

And your template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login">
    {{#view App.LoginFormView}}
        <label>
          Username:
          {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.username"}} 
        </label>
        <label>
          Password:
          {{view Ember.TextField type="password" valueBinding="view.password"}}
        </label>
        <button>Login</button>
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

**Edit:** After some thought, probably all the logic I put into the controller should actually go to the router. Controllers should be used for connecting models to views.

Comment: I did not understood why logic should go to router. Because as per MVC logic should go to the controller

Comment: I think there is some issue in the code in the script tag if I remove this data-template-name="login" it works, otherwise it fails. U know what is the reason?

Comment: The line -> var username = this.get('login') should be this.get('username')

Comment: Shouldn't `App.loginController = Ember.Object.create` be `App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend`?

Comment: how will be the routes?

Answer (score 2):

I built a login form yesterday, I assume you want to build an asynchronous one.

I started out by looking at this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1477225), the API has changed a bit since then however so now it looks a bit different:

JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.loginController = Ember.Object.create({
    // do login stuff
});

App.LoginFormView = Ember.View.extend({
    username: null,
    password: null,

    submitLogin: function() {
        var username = this.get('login');
        var password = this.get('password');
        console.log('Login: ' + login + ' Password: ' + password);

        // do the login, probably by $.post()ing to your login page
    },
});
```

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="login">
    {{#view App.LoginFormView tagName="form"}}
        <label>Username:</label>
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="view.username"}} 
        <label>Password:</label>
        {{view Ember.TextField type="password" valueBinding="view.password"}}
        {{#view Ember.Button target="parentView" action="submitLogin"}}Login{{/view}}
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

As for your other questions, I can't answer them completely (I'm relatively new to Ember.js), but I think the core philosophy of Ember.js is to mostly be an architectural framework (but with nice tie-ins to Handlebars.js), not an architectural *and* UI framework like its predecessor, [SproutCore](http://sproutcore.com/).

Comment: See Alexander Zaytsev's code, it's better. All the changes he made are changes I made to my real, working code, I just took the code from that gist almost verbatim and forgot to apply the changes again.